# I have a program generate a text file, and a 2nd program to read data from that file and generate new output

Tags: python

I'm using the following program to generate a text file with a car model and the number of gallons it uses to drive 100 miles (all fictional):

```py
try:
    with open('fuel_economy_data.txt', 'w') as f:
        for i in range(1, 6):
            car_model = input("Enter the model of car {} tested: ".format(i))
            gallons_used = float(input("Enter the number of gallons used for car {} tested: ".format(i)))
            f.write("Model: {}, Gallons used: {}\n".format(car_model, gallons_used))
    print("Data saved to fuel_economy_data.txt")
except Exception as e:
    print("Error: ", e)
```

I have another program intended to read from the generated text file mentioned above, the car models and their gallons used should be read as a pair from the file. I have to determine the fuel efficiency (miles per gallon) for each car by dividing the miles driven by the gallons used where the output would appear like so:

The program's output should appear as shown below:

```bash
Model      MPG
--------- 
aaa         xx.x
```

Where `aaa` is the model and `xx.x` is the MPG.

For this functionality, I used the following code:

```py
try:
    # Open the fuel economy data file for reading
    with open('fuel_economy_data.txt', 'r') as file:
        # Print the header row
        print("{:<20}{}".format("MODEL", "MPG"))
        print("-" * 30)
        # Loop through each line in the file
        for line in file:
            # Strip the newline character and split the line into a list
            data = line.strip().split()
            # Extract the model and gallons used from the list
            model = data[0]
            gallons_used = float(data[1])
            # Calculate the miles per gallon for the current car
            mpg = 100 / gallons_used
            # Print the model and its corresponding miles per gallon
            print("{:<20}{:.1f}".format(model, mpg))

except FileNotFoundError:
    print("Error: fuel_economy_data.txt not found.")
except ValueError:
    print("Error: invalid data in fuel_economy_data.txt.")
except Exception as e:
    print("Error:", e)
```

Consequently, I'm getting the following error message:

`Error: invalid data in fuel_economy_data.txt.`

I get this error message immediately when I run the second program. I'm looking through my code and cannot decipher what the reading problem is. I am fairly new to this, please do not judge me too harshly.

Comment: Sorry, part of my question ended up in the code container.

Comment: Catching exceptions in this way may hide valuable debug information. From module `traceback` you can add function call `print_exc()` to the except-block to retrieve a full traceback with much more error details.

Comment: Thank you so much for your assistance, I was able to move forward with this.

Answer (score 0):

When you are using exception handling you are hiding the original error messages. The best way is to get the original ones and try to debug them. When you are aware of all possible errors you can try excepting some of them if catching them is logical.

For your program you can extract car model and gallons_used easier with the code below:

```py
data = data.split(':')

model = data[1].split(',')[0].strip()
gallons_used = float(data[-1].strip())
mpg = 100 / gallons_used

print("{:<20}{:.1f}".format(model, mpg))
```

So the final program should be like this:

```py
# Open the fuel economy data file for reading
with open('fuel_economy_data.txt', 'r') as file:
    # Print the header row
    print("{:<20}{}".format("MODEL", "MPG"))
    print("-" * 30)
    # Loop through each line in the file
    for line in file:
        # Strip the newline character and split the line into a list
        data = line.strip()

        data = data.split(':')

        #  Extract the model and gallons used from the list
        model = data[1].split(',')[0].strip()
        gallons_used = float(data[-1].strip())

        # Calculate the miles per gallon for the current car
        mpg = 100 / gallons_used

        # Print the model and its corresponding miles per gallon
        print("{:<20}{:.1f}".format(model, mpg))
```

If the file contain this:

```
Model: a, Gallons used: 1.0
Model: b, Gallons used: 2.0
Model: c, Gallons used: 3.0
Model: d, Gallons used: 4.0
Model: e, Gallons used: 5.0
```

The output of the second program would look like this:

```
MODEL               MPG
------------------------------
a                   100.0
b                   50.0
c                   33.3
d                   25.0
e                   20.0
```

Try to use exceptions when necessary as using inappropriate exception handling can cause program disfunction.